# Error when starting terminal: "-bash: QSTK/local.sh: No such file or directory"

Tags: command-line, terminal

"-bash: QSTK/local.sh: No such file or directory"

I've been getting this error for over a year. Any idea how I'd go about fixing it? None of the similar suggestions on SO solve this problem.

**In response to Olivier's suggestion:**

When I run

```
grep QSTK/local\.sh'  /etc/*   ~/.??*
```

I get this output:

```
grep: /etc/aliases.db: Permission denied
grep: /etc/kcpassword: Permission denied
grep: /etc/krb5.keytab: Permission denied
grep: /etc/master.passwd: Permission denied
grep: /etc/sudoers: Permission denied
/Users/DylanRichards/.bash_profile:source QSTK/local.sh
/Users/DylanRichards/.bash_profile.pysave:source QSTK/local.sh
/Users/DylanRichards/.profile:source QSTK/local.sh
Dylan-Richardss-MacBook-Pro:~ DylanRichards$
```

When I type

```
-type f -size -200 -print0 2>/dev/null | xargs -0 grep 'QSTK/local\.sh' /dev/null
```

It returns nothing. The error is still occurring at the start of my terminal.

Comment: when do you get it? at startup? each time you open a terminal?

Comment: Yep. That's when I get it.

Answer (score 0):

following your answers to my questions:

to look for the script responsible, first in the shell's startup scripts:

```
grep 'QSTK/local\.sh'  /etc/*   ~/.??*
```

and if it is not enough:

```
find / -type f -size -200 -print0 2>/dev/null | xargs -0 grep 'QSTK/local\.sh' /dev/null
```

(just copy/paste this, while loggued as root in a terminal window, so that you can grep most files)

(the additional "/dev/null" is there to force grep to display the matching file's name even if there is only 1 parameter, which cuold happen if xargs split in a way that make the last file alone)

(I only check files of less than around 100kb [100 x 512 bytes], as anything bigger is most probably a binary and not a script...)

Note that this could fail if "QSTK" is in a variable, or is contructed...

But it could work. Try it and let us know if it's enough for you to correct the mistake, or provide additionnal informations if you don't know how to proceed.

=== update =====================

after you posted:

```
/Users/DylanRichards/.bash_profile:source QSTK/local.sh
/Users/DylanRichards/.bash_profile.pysave:source QSTK/local.sh
/Users/DylanRichards/.profile:source QSTK/local.sh
```

I'd recommend you

- 1) check that you have, indeed, a `/Users/DylanRichards/QSTK/local.sh` file.

  `ls -l /Users/DylanRichards/QSTK/local.sh`
- 2) check its content and **ensure you are OK to execute it each time you log-on**

  `more /Users/DylanRichards/QSTK/local.sh`
- 3) **if** it is OK to execute it (ie, **if** it's really something you really need/want to execute at each login) then

  `chmod +x /Users/DylanRichards/QSTK/local.sh`
   `ls -al /Users/DylanRichards/QSTK/local.sh`

You can, if you want, post the info of the `ls -l /Users/DylanRichards/QSTK/local.sh`

But as for its content, please verify it (do not post it here if it could contain important security information...). (If however you feel it's safe to show it to us, you can post the : `cat /Users/DylanRichards/QSTK/local.sh`  (unless it's more than 20 lines...)

Finally, in case you do NOT find the file in /Users/DylanRichards/QSTK/local.sh :

```
find / -type f -name "local.sh" -print 2>/dev/null | grep QSTK/local.sh
```

will show you where it is. Once again, check its content, and if it seems fine (and needed) edit the ~/.bash_profile and ~/.profile with the correct path to the correct file.

Comment: Hey, @Olivier I have updated the question with what the terminal generated after typing in your command.

Comment: Edited main post again. @Olivier

Comment: @DylanRichards: i updated the answer again, based on your new informations

Answer (score 0):

open .bashrc file using a text editor as follows

$gedit  .bashrc

In the text file look for the path .QSTK/local.sh probably in the last line you may something similar to
VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1 source /home/QSTK/local.sh

comment out the line adding a # in the beginning of the line and then save

Try it out